# Fast report designer run-time does not appear

Tags: delphi, fastreport

i just set at my VCL app a `TfrxReport` and then i just do a button click event to show the report designer when the application run , but the problem here is that the run time designer never appear to me ...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 frxReport1.DesignReport;
end;
```

Comment: What Delphi version, and what version of FastReports? According to Code Completion in XE4, `DesignReport` requires two parameters be passed. It's defined as `TfrxReport.DesignReport(IDesigner: IInterface; Editor: TObject );`, so the code you've posted not only won't run, it also will not compile.

Comment: i'm using delphi Xe2 update 3 
and fast report entreprise edition 4.12.6

and yes when i used to write the name of the method the auto completer show me two option that one you said , and another method  with to boolean parameter for me i tried with passing no parameter and it not work and then with two boolean  parameter and it either not work ... if you have an exeple of how to use that method please write it here .

Comment: I don't have one (I don't use FR). I just looked at it to try and see what was wrong for you, and noticed two parameters (as I mentioned) in Code Completion. If I had an example, I would have posted an answer instead of a comment. I can't help you, because your code won't even compile in my version of Delphi. I have FR v 4.13.2 that ships with Delphi XE4.

Comment: @KenWhite The code completion does show the method you list.  However, there is a different DesignReport(Modal: Boolean = True; MDIChild: Boolean = False), so the code in the question will compile and run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to place a `frxDesigner` component on the Form or Datamodule keeping your frxReport component to enable runtime design.

Comment: I don't have that that component i can(t find it in the list of fast report components ... do you think that my version is not completed .. ?

Comment: Designer is included from the Standard Version, (I'm unable to add the featurematrix). Without the Component designing at runtime is not possible. Since you mentioned having an enterprise version maybe something went wrong through installation.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.

1. Open Delphi
2. Follow the path Tools>Options>Library
3. Add Library Path Fast_report_install_folder\source
4. add to part

   interface
   uses
   frxDesgn,frxDesgnCtrls, ....................
5. Now it will run the following code

   ```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        begin
        frxReport1.DesignReport;
    end;
   ```

It is written in 2013. I've had the same problem and solved it. Maybe it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop TFrxDesigner from Tool Platte. inside your TFrxReport

```
frxReport1.DesignReport;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still use some FR Embarcadero edition packages. Uninstall all instances of FR, remove all FR's files and folders (see system and hidden folders too) and then install FR Enterprise again